# Equivalent code of hash in .Net to Python 2.7

Tags: .net, python-2.7, sha256, hmac

I have a code in .Net to generate HMAC SHA256 hash. I tried my best to get the equivalent code in Python 2.7 but it differs. Where am I going wrong?

.Net code

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;                  
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var key = Guid.Parse("7a640e1f-df45-4652-a9d5-4bdc2003deac").ToByteArray();
        var payload = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ab38eadaeb746599f2c1ee90f8267f31f467347462764a24d71ac1843ee77fe3#40011234567890##34567####MitErpNavn#34567#20170719192159");
        Console.WriteLine(key);
        Console.WriteLine(payload);
        for(var i = 0; i < key.Length;i++)
        {
            var b = key[i];
            Console.WriteLine(b);
        }
        using(var ha = new HMACSHA256(key))
        {
           var hash = ha.ComputeHash(payload);
           var result = Convert.ToBase64String(hash); 
           Console.WriteLine(result);

        }
    }
}

Output: f0UqIWmJBea+rTixF1jiCNhEt12yPN4R7gJclYMM3mE=
```

Python 2.7

```
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64
import uuid

erp_key = '7a640e1f-df45-4652-a9d5-4bdc2003deac'
payload = 'ab38eadaeb746599f2c1ee90f8267f31f467347462764a24d71ac1843ee77fe3#40011234567890##34567####MitErpNavn#34567#20170719192159'
erp_uuid = uuid.UUID(erp_key)
dig = hmac.new(erp_uuid.bytes, msg=payload, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()
hash_key = base64.b64encode(dig).decode()

print hash_key

Output: wI/WinRP4mHfHLnFCSHn6j4VphSOO8CjLqkAVJi1HTQ=
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I am able to fix the issue. I hope someone else can also get help from this

```
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64
import uuid
import array

erp_key = '7a640e1f-df45-4652-a9d5-4bdc2003deac'
payload = 'ab38eadaeb746599f2c1ee90f8267f31f467347462764a24d71ac1843ee77fe3#40011234567890##34567####MitErpNavn#34567#20170719192159'

erp_uuid = uuid.UUID(erp_key)
map_arr = array.array('B', erp_uuid.bytes_le)
makeitastring = "".join(chr(x) for x in map_arr)

dig = hmac.new(makeitastring, payload, hashlib.sha256).digest()
hash_key = base64.b64encode(dig).decode()

encodedSignature = base64.encodestring(dig).replace('\n', '')

print encodedSignature

Output: f0UqIWmJBea+rTixF1jiCNhEt12yPN4R7gJclYMM3mE=
```